# Upload multiple files in one HTTP request

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

Is there any way to upload multiple files in one HTTP request using cordova. I found all solution that uses separate HTTP call for each image upload.

Comment: the only option is using multiple input type file to select the files, but it doesn't work on some android versions

Answer (score 0):

I asked Raymond camden same question. He replied me with this awesome blog.

I simply used the Camera plugin to let you select multiple images from the device. Each image is added to the DOM. Here is that code:

```
var images = [];
var $imagesDiv;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);
function init() {

    $("#addPicture").on("touchend", selPic);
    $imagesDiv = $("#images");  
    $("#uploadPictures").on("touchend", uploadPics);
}

function selPic() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(function(f) {
        var newHtml = "<img src='"+f+"'>";
        $imagesDiv.append(newHtml);
        images.push(f);
        if(images.length === 1) {
            $("#uploadPictures").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    }, function(e) {
        alert("Error, check console.");
        console.dir(e);
    }, { 
        quality: 50,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
    });

}
```

As you can guess, the upload button at the bottom there will begin the process. For my testing, I set up a ColdFusion script to simply save the uploads to a temporary directory. To add a bit of randonmness though, it will randomly reject images by outputting 0. On successful uploads, it will output 1.

Here is the remainder of the code:

```
function uploadPics() {
    console.log("Ok, going to upload "+images.length+" images.");
    var defs = [];

    images.forEach(function(i) {
        console.log('processing '+i);
        var def = $.Deferred();

        function win(r) {
            console.log("thing done");
            if($.trim(r.response) === "0") {
                console.log("this one failed");
                def.resolve(0);
            } else {
                console.log("this one passed");
                def.resolve(1);
            }
        }

        function fail(error) {
            console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
            console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
            def.resolve(0);
        }

        var uri = encodeURI("http://localhost/testingzone/test.cfm");

        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=i.substr(i.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(i, uri, win, fail, options);
        defs.push(def.promise());

    });

    $.when.apply($, defs).then(function() {
        console.log("all things done");
        console.dir(arguments);
    });

}
```

So from top to bottom, what I’m doing is creating an array of promise objects. Or more specifically, the jQuery version of them. I then run an upload call for each image selected by the user. I check the result from the server and either resolve the promise with 0 or 1 based on what the server said.

Finally, I’ve got a call to $.when to handle waiting for all these asynch processes to finish. I don’t actually show anything, I just console.dir, but you could imagine checking the results and doing – well – whatever makes sense.

I hope this is useful for folks, and as always, let me know if you have any questions. You can find the complete source here: https://github.com/cfjedimaster/Cordova-Examples/tree/master/multiupload

Resource: [Raymond Camden's Blog](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/08/10/processing-multiple-simultaneous-uploads-with-cordova)

Comment: but here each image upload will call separate HTTP call right ? I am talking about uploading all image in a single HTTP call

Answer (score 0):

from my side, I am trying to zip all images/files in one file and then upload the single zip file.
The issue for this potential solution : find a cordova zip function for both android & ios